# Summing items in an array -- in a DataFrame -- in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on some code that shows the distribution of topic models over time. Right now, the dataframe looks something like this:

```
doc_id  date        topic_dist
1       2007-01-01  [.2,.5,.3]
2       2007-03-02  [.8,.1,.1]
...
```

My goal is to group the documents by date (by month, year, or quarter), and sum each of the items in the arrays (all arrays are the same length), to create an output that looks something like:

```
month    topic_sum
2007-01  [54.8, 98.3, 61.0]
```

So far, I tried

```
year_groups = df.groupby(df['date'].map(lambda x: x.year))
output = pd.DataFrame()
output['yearly_topic_dist'] = year_groups.apply(lambda x: sum(x['topic_dist']))
```

So, I can't figure out how to sum each of the items in the array separately, and output another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be doing something wrong, but @piRSquared's solution seems to break with the example DataFrame below when you group by one month. Though it does not break with a 12 month group. I guess it has to do with dates spanning over one year.

Another option is to just cast the topic_dist column to Numpy arrays and apply an np.sum() to your time groups:

```
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2007-01-01', [.2, .5, .3]],
                   [2, '2007-01-02', [.8, .5, .3]],
                   [3, '2008-01-14', [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]],
                 columns=['doc_id', 'date', 'topic_dist'])


df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df = df.set_index('date')

df.topic_dist = df.topic_dist.apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
```

You can group by a single month.

```
# Group by single months
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))['topic_dist'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x))

date
2007-01-31    [1.0, 1.0, 0.6]
2007-02-28                  0
2007-03-31                  0
2007-04-30                  0
2007-05-31                  0
2007-06-30                  0
2007-07-31                  0
2007-08-31                  0
2007-09-30                  0
2007-10-31                  0
2007-11-30                  0
2007-12-31                  0
2008-01-31    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
Name: topic_dist, dtype: object
```

Or group by 12 months:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('12M'))['topic_dist'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x))
date
2007-01-31    [1.0, 1.0, 0.6]
2008-01-31    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
Name: topic_dist, dtype: object
```

Or other intervals:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5M'))['topic_dist'].apply(lambda x: np.sum(x))
date
2007-01-31    [1.0, 1.0, 0.6]
2007-06-30                  0
2007-11-30                  0
2008-04-30    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
Name: topic_dist, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2007-01-01', [.2, .5, .3]],
                   [2, '2007-01-02', [.8, .5, .3]]],
                 columns=['doc_id', 'date', 'topic_dist'])

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df = df.set_index('date')
```

#### Solution

```
def topic_adder(s):
    return s.apply(pd.Series).sum().tolist()

df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))['topic_dist'].apply(topic_adder)
```

looks like:

```
date
2007-01-31    [1.0, 1.0, 0.6]
Name: topic_dist, dtype: object
```